# How do I sort comma separated number without distorted in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem with the sorting of comma separated value. It sorts fine when I remove the comma but immediate reintroduce the function to it. It is all gone. 
The data is generated from backend, it is randomised. I have an image of what the present code is doing. 
[image]
instead to be aligned beneath respective products;
[image]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
    function numberWithCommas(number) {
    var parts = number.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");
}
    $('div div .swiper-wrapper li.swiper-slide').sort(function(a, b) {
            var $field = $('div div .swiper-wrapper li.swiper-slide .home-stats .price p span');
            var aValue = parseFloat($(a).find($field).text());
            var bValue = parseFloat($(b).find($field).text());
            if (aValue > bValue)
              return 1;
            if (aValue < bValue)
              return -1;
            return 0;
  }).appendTo('div ul.swiper-wrapper');
        $("div div .swiper-wrapper li.swiper-slide .home-stats .price p span.number").each(function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
    var commaNum = numberWithCommas(num);
    $(this).text(commaNum);
  }).appendTo('div ul.swiper-wrapper');

});

});
```

The prices are removed from the products and displayed offset (not aligned or tallied to the respective products) but sorted with comma appropriately

Comment: can u add data instead of jquery.

Comment: Please, do you mean the data to be sorted?

Comment: yes, it is hard to check without data, only with jquery code. console.log on state. it will be ok

Comment: The data is coming from the backend and it is randomised but I have screenshot of the output of the current code. However, we can test with several number 1,000,000  200,000  3,000 200 10 etc

Comment: i think befor var aValue = parseFloat($(a).find($field).text());,parseFloat, remove ","

Comment: There is no "," there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to wrap the second function calling in setTimeout function as the two functions are concurrently being executed at the same time. 
You can check the code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(window).load(function() {
   // function to create format
        function numberWithCommas(number) {
    var parts = number.toString().split(".");
    parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return parts.join(".");

    // Sort function
    $('div div .swiper-wrapper li.swiper-slide').sort(function(a, b) {
            var $field = $('div div .swiper-wrapper li.swiper-slide .home-stats .price p span');
            var aValue = parseFloat($(a).find($field).text());
            var bValue = parseFloat($(b).find($field).text());

            if (aValue > bValue)
              return 1;
            if (aValue < bValue)
              return -1;
            return 0;
  }).appendTo('div ul.swiper-wrapper');
 // setTimeout function for implementing the format
         setTimeout(function() {
   $("div div .swiper-wrapper li.swiper-slide .home-stats .price p span.number").each(function() {
    var num = $(this).text();
    var commaNum = numberWithCommas(num);
    $(this).text(commaNum);
       console.log(commaNum);

  });}, 2000);
});

});
```

This is all you need to avoid the two functions being called at the document.ready or window.load

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I didn't even think about that.